# Cron tasks disappeared on Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud, cron, whenever, engineyard

Hello everywhere!

I've realized strange issue on engine yard. At second time cron tasks were vanished. We have there two instances. We use whenever gem with deployment hook to renew tasks when server is restarted. This issue appeared when I changed deployment hook for make cron jobs running only on master instance(for not to duplicate processes).

I suppose that this happens when takeover process is performed. So slave becomes the master(Viva Metallica) and on this instance are no cron jobs until deployment script is runned again.

Am I right? How to solve this?
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are only installed onto the application master instance. When your application master fails and a failover occurs, the cron jobs do not automatically transfer to the promoted instance. You can re-run Chef by pressing the "Apply" button on the dashboard to have these cron jobs restored.

This information is documented here: http://docs.engineyard.com/instance-takeover.html

Additionally, submitting a ticket to the Engine Yard support team (https://support.cloud.engineyard.com) will yield a faster and more informed response than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm interesting how to re-run it automatically when takeover happens.